# Django ManyToManyField not saving in admin

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
document_type_d = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType,
                                    verbose_name="Document Type")

class Section(models.Model):
document_type_s = models.ManyToManyField(DocumentType,
                                         verbose_name="Document Type")

class DocumentType(models.Model):
document_type_dt = models.CharField("Document Type", max_length=240)
```

When I create a Section in the Admin it doesn't appear to save the document_type_s.

In the django shell I can see that DocumentType is saving properly:

```
>>> dt = DocumentType.objects.all()
>>> for d in dt:
...     print d.document_type_dt
... 
Campus LAN
WAN
Unified Communications
```

When I check the Sections I get:

```
>>> original_sections = Section.objects.all()
>>> for a in original_sections:
...     print a.document_type_s
... 
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
```

And when I check Documents:

```
>>> d = Document.objects.all()
>>> for e in d:
...     print e.document_type_d
... 
Campus LAN
WAN
Campus LAN
```

And if I try to create a new section:

```
>>> s = Section(document_type_s="Campus LAN", name="Fake", original=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 480, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'document_type_s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Django appears to have created the field in the database, looking at my migrations file:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Section',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('document_type_s', models.ManyToManyField(to='lld.DocumentType', verbose_name=b'Document Type')),
            ]
```

I don't know what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as far as I understand, the ManyToManyField in the Section class doesn't actually save any DocumentType data in the Section database table, rather it saves the relationship to DocumentType.
Therefore if I want to access the document_type of a section I have to look up the Section objects via the DocumentType object, and vice versa.

For instance:

```
>>> DocumentType.objects.get(name="WAN").section_set.all()
[<Section: ALL 1>, <Section: ALL 2>, <Section: WAN 5>, <Section: WAN 6>]
>>> DocumentType.objects.get(name="Campus LAN").section_set.all()
[<Section: ALL 1>, <Section: ALL 2>, <Section: Campus LAN 3>, <Section: Campus LAN 4>]
```

or:

```
>>> Section.objects.filter(document_type_s__name="WAN")
[<Section: ALL 1>, <Section: ALL 2>, <Section: WAN 5>, <Section: WAN 6>]
```

or:

```
>>> DocumentType.objects.filter(section__name__startswith="Campus")
[<DocumentType: Campus LAN>, <DocumentType: Campus LAN>]
```

Although this:

```
>>> DocumentType.objects.filter(section__document_type_s="WAN")
```

raises `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'WAN'` because there is no data under the section_document_type m2m field, only the relationship.  So this is still the case:

```
>>> original_sections = Section.objects.all()
>>> for a in original_sections:
...     print a.document_type_s
... 
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
lld.DocumentType.None
```

Further info [here](https://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/db/examples/many_to_many.html).

Answer (score 1):

How do you think this is going to work?

```
Section(document_type_s="Campus LAN", name="Fake", original=True)
```

`document_type_s` is a ManyToMany field but you are passing in a string value

Read the docs for ManyToMany:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

For many to many relation to be created the `Section` instance already has to exist (because in the db a m2m relation is an extra table with two foreign keys)... so you need to:

```
dt = DocumentType.objects.get(pk=1)
section = Section.objects.create(name="Fake", original=True)
section.document_type_s.add(dt)
```

Comment: Yeah, that I get.  I got it wrong trying to create it in the shell, I see that.  My main problem, though, is that the DocumentType options exist, they have been created in the admin.  When I create a new Section in the admin I can choose from the DocumentType options, but that choice is not being saved.

Comment: m2m fields work fine in the django admin, are you using standard django admin or something else?

Comment: actually, I'm using django-admin-bootstrapped.  I'll try removing it.  So from what you can see, creating a Section should save the document_type_s field to the database?

Comment: nope, removing django-admin-bootstrapped doesn't make a difference.

Comment: no, creating a `Section` won't save the `document_type_s` field to the db, that's not how m2m fields work

Comment: ok, I'm going to re-read the docs, see if I can't figure this out, thanks @Anentropic